# Safari not loading correct font type

Tags: css, google-fonts

I just moved my fonts from Google fonts to local storage for GDPR reasons.
Unfortunately the fonts are not loading in Safari any longer.
I am a little lost.

Everything seems fine in Chrome and Firefox. Caching is also not the issue, as I am using a private window.

This is what I am doing in my CSS

```
/* montserrat-300 - vietnamese_latin-ext_latin_cyrillic-ext_cyrillic */    
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Montserrat';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 300;
  src: local(''),
       url('/static/fonts/montserrat-v21-vietnamese_latin-ext_latin_cyrillic-    ext_cyrillic-300.woff2') format('woff2'), /* Chrome 26+, Opera 23+, Firefox 39+ */
       url('/static/fonts/montserrat-v21-vietnamese_latin-ext_latin_cyrillic-ext_cyrillic-300.woff') format('woff'); /* Chrome 6+, Firefox 3.6+, IE 9+, Safari 5.1+                 
*/
}
/* montserrat-regular - vietnamese_latin-ext_latin_cyrillic-ext_cyrillic */
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Montserrat';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  src: local(''),
       url('/static/fonts/montserrat-v21-vietnamese_latin-ext_latin_cyrillic-ext_cyrillic-regular.woff2') format('woff2'), /* Chrome 26+, Opera 23+, Firefox 39+ */
       url('/static/fonts/montserrat-v21-vietnamese_latin-ext_latin_cyrillic-ext_cyrillic-regular.woff') format('woff'); /* Chrome 6+, Firefox 3.6+, IE 9+, Safari 5.1+ */
}
/* montserrat-700 - vietnamese_latin-ext_latin_cyrillic-ext_cyrillic */
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Montserrat';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 700;
  src: local(''),
       url('/static/fonts/montserrat-v21-vietnamese_latin-ext_latin_cyrillic-ext_cyrillic-700.woff2') format('woff2'), /* Chrome 26+, Opera 23+, Firefox 39+ */
       url('/static/fonts/montserrat-v21-vietnamese_latin-ext_latin_cyrillic-ext_cyrillic-700.woff') format('woff'); /* Chrome 6+, Firefox 3.6+, IE 9+, Safari 5.1+     */
}

body {
  font-family: "Montserrat", sans-serif;
}
```

Any hint is welcome.

Comment: I have found that when pulling down fonts, the permissions often disallow reading. I'd expect that to affect all browsers, but it's worth a check.

Comment: Unlikely the cause of the problem, but you appear to have a 4 space gap in the first font URL that I doubt is meant to be there. Also, it's worth making sure you clear the caches in Chrome/Firefox to make sure you aren't getting a false positive there (just in case)

Comment: CSP is not active at the moment. This is happening in production and locally, so I doubt that this is the problem. I am also able to access the font files directly.

Comment: Thanks for the hint with the Caches, I cleared them and the result is as described above. :-(

Comment: Is your site/page public? Can you add a link to it?